# Should I expect a whole-home humidifier to provide consistent humidity throughout a 3-story townhouse?

Tags: hvac, humidity, humidifier

I'm looking to [install a whole-home humidifier](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/208013/56531) in my 3-story townhouse in northern Virginia. I already have trouble keeping a consistent temperature throughout the 3 stories - should I expect similar trouble keeping the humidity consistent? If so, will the humidity tend to be higher on the lower floor or upper floor, and will that result in humidity that's too high on one floor in order to get it comfortable on another?

Comment: Is any part of the house in sunlight at some times and not others?  What color is the roof and sun-facing walls?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica back of the house is beige vinyl and gets the morning sun. Front is red brick and gets the afternoon sun. Both sides are shared walls. Roof is black (grey?).